# I am trying to get my CDN to work with my site. I am not sure what is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, magnific-popup

this is what I have in the  section.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Motion Graphics</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/CSS/motiongallery.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a248c1791d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../script/videogallery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-bLT0Qm9VnAYZDflyKcBaQ2gg0hSYNQrJ8RilYldYQ1FxQYoCLtUjuuRuZo+fjqhx/qtq/1itJ0C2ejDxltZVFg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" integrity="sha512-IsNh5E3eYy3tr/JiX2Yx4vsCujtkhwl7SLqgnwLNgf04Hrt9BT9SXlLlZlWx+OK4ndzAoALhsMNcCmkggjZB1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</head>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong but if I put this in codepen.io and put the cdn in the settings there it works so I don't think it is the
CDN link.

I am trying to get my video gallery that when you click on a certain video instead of bringing you to the link it creates a pop up while leaving you on my webpage.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I see that you provided the contents of your HEAD. But haven't provided enough to actually test it out and see what is wrong. I would recommend checking out [mcve]. However, one note is the problem could be that your javascript is the in the HEAD and your videogallery code is trying to attach to elements not loaded yet.

Comment: Are you running any addons/extensions that would block those scripts?

Comment: This might have several reasons. Content Security Policy (CSP), tools that block external scripts, etc. Have you checked with your browser's DevTools that these scripts are loaded.